# reading line-oriented data using C# Async sockets

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp

I am new to C#, but have done TCP and socket programming many years.
I would like to create a program that does async I/O (receiving only) from
multiple servers.  The data is text and is delimited by newlines (very easy).

My question is about whether I can assume that if I use a StreamReader
in my async read callback function, whether I can assume that

1. It will be able to get at least a complete line of data, and
2. That it will not somehow block.

The way I understand it, I wantto do a StreamReader ReadLine in my
async read callback.  But what in the BeginRead would *know* that I really
want to do line-oriented data?  I obviously don't know the length to read
at that point.

I hope this makes sense, and thanks in advance!

Mitch

Answer (score 1):

From your post I think that you need to create your own class, and wrap ***SYNCHRONOUS*** socket into it.  You will `Read()` the socket in a blocking fashion, buffer the data, split lines and fire up event to the class consumer when whole line is available.

Comment: +1 So true. (I did edit your question to make SYNC italic+bold to ***really*** point it out).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of your question: you're intending to use the `StreamReader` like a blocking stream, yet you're using asynchronous sockets... even if my understanding is wrong, please still see the suggestions below since they also cover the case where you're really intending to use the `StreamReader` for asynchronous reading.

1. It will be able to get at least a complete line of data, and
   Yes and no: it will read a complete line of data as long as the underlying buffer has a new line, however, this is an async event so once the `StreamReader` runs out of data (i.e. it reaches the last new line) it will no longer have anything to read, even if you get another async callback. Basically, you bind your receive buffer to the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` and when you get a callback, your buffer is filled. What you do with the buffer after that is up to you (you may feed it into a `StreamReader` to read the line input).
2. That it will not somehow block.
   It won't block, but it won't get all the data you're looking for depending on how you implement your async callback. Which brings me to my next point...

**My next point:** I don't know if this is a continuous stream of data, or just some line delimited "batch" of data, however, you have several options:

1. Use 1 memory stream and a read/write stream associated with that memory stream. Whenever you get a callback you write the buffer using the `StreamWriter` and you read the lines using the `StreamReader` until you can no longer read any new lines.
2. Keep writing the buffer to a stream until you receive no more bytes from the socket (i.e. you get a 0 for the bytes received) and then use that stream to initialize your `StreamReader`, then read all the lines. This assumes that you have a fixed size of incoming data, rather than a continuous flow of "input".
3. Create a blocking reader and let it live on a separate thread, it only reads when the async read raises a flag of some sort (think `ManualResetEvent` or something along the lines). It kinda defeats the purpose of asynchronous sockets, but it still lets you take advantage of the benefits. It's a little better than pure blocking sockets, because the blocking is entirely controlled by you.

I would assume that your best option is #1, but the other 2 may not be out of the question depending on what you're trying to do.

On a side note: I've [created an async HTTP client](http://codesprout.blogspot.com/2011/04/asynchronous-http-client.html), so feel free to take a look at it and scavenge whatever you find useful.  I would assume that these two functions are going to be the most important for you:

Begin Receiving:

```
private void BeginReceive()
{
    if ( _clientState == EClientState.Receiving)
    {
        if (_asyncTask.BytesReceived != 0 && _asyncTask.TotalBytesReceived <= _maxPageSize)
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            e.SetBuffer(_asyncTask.ReceiveBuffer, 0, _asyncTask.ReceiveBuffer.Length);
            e.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(ReceiveCallback);
            e.UserToken = _asyncTask.Host;

            bool comletedAsync = false;
            try
            {
                comletedAsync = _socket.ReceiveAsync(e);
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error receiving data from: " + _asyncTask.Host);
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0} Error Code: {1}", se.Message, se.NativeErrorCode);

                ChangeState(EClientState.Failed);
            }

            if (!comletedAsync)
            {
                // The call completed synchronously so invoke the callback ourselves
                ReceiveCallback(this, e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Num bytes received: " + _asyncTask.TotalBytesReceived);
            ChangeState(EClientState.ReceiveDone);
        }
    }
}
```

And the ReceiveCallback:

```
private void ReceiveCallback(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
{
    lock (_sync) // re-entrant lock
    {
        // Fast fail: should not be receiving data if the client
        // is not in a receiving state.
        if (_clientState == EClientState.Receiving)
        {
            String host = (String)args.UserToken;

            if (_asyncTask.Host == host && args.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
            {
                try
                {
                    Encoding encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
                    _asyncTask.BytesReceived = args.BytesTransferred;
                    _asyncTask.TotalBytesReceived += _asyncTask.BytesReceived;

                    // ********************************************
                    // You will need to replace the following line:
                    _asyncTask.DocSource += encoding.GetString(_asyncTask.ReceiveBuffer, 0, _asyncTask.BytesReceived);

                    // Write the contents of the ReceiveBuffer to a Stream using a StreamWriter

                    // Use the StreamReader associated with the same Stream to read the next line(s)
                    // ********************************************
                    BeginReceive();
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error receiving data from: " + host);
                    Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0} Error Code: {1}", e.Message, e.NativeErrorCode);

                    ChangeState(EClientState.Failed);
                }
            }
            else if (_asyncTask.Host != host)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Warning: received a callback for {0}, but the client is currently working on {1}.",
                    host, _asyncTask.Host);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket Error: {0} when receiving from {1}",
                   args.SocketError,
                   _asyncTask.Host);
                ChangeState(EClientState.Failed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you won't be quite able to do this with built-in classes.

You can use `StreamReader` on a `NetworkStream` to read whole lines, but you will need to code the async part yourself as `StreamReader` does not expose an async interface. Alternatively, you could use `NetworkStream.BeginRead` which is async, but then you would have to write the code to make it recognize line-based input.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  My first thought was to use separate threads, but then several people have told me they won't scale as well as using async I/O.

Comment: @Mitchell McConnell: Several people must then learn the KISS principle. Do the easiest possible solution you can until it doesn't scale anymore. Then refactor to make the code faster.

Comment: @MitchellMcConnell: Add me to those people. So it seems that the `BeginRead`/custom parsing method would be best for you. Look into `System.Text.Decoder` (which you would get with System.Text.Encoding.GetDecoder`), which exists specifically to decode text read from a stream.

Comment: @Jon: Please explain why it's better when he is coding a client (although connecting to several servers)?

Comment: @jgauffin: I don't think that explicit threading is inherently easier to write than explicit byte buffer manipulation. But we do know that async I/O is inherently better than threaded.

Comment: Have you done performance testing to see how many sockets is needed to get better performance with the async methods? And how much less CPU do really async ops gain for lets say 30 sockets? Using sync operations allows him to use `StreamReader` which makes the whole handling a whole lot easier.

Comment: @jgauffin: I have not. Have you written the code to make the reads async for 30 sockets and compare it for length and ease of modification to the alternative?

Comment: I've written several synchronous and asynchronous clients **and** servers the last ten years and also built a few SDKs for different internet protocols. So yes, you can say that.

Comment: @jgauffin: I would be entitled to disagree even if you had written Berkeley sockets though.

Comment: Normally, I am 110% in the KISS camp, which is why I started with separate threads, which can block, do ReadLines, etc.  But the requirements are for over 200 servers sending data, and I didn't know if separate threads would scale that far.

I am comfortable, however, with async I/O, having done several communication projects like that in the past (Unix, C).

Comment: BTW, I have a client app (stream ripper app, wma, shoutcast, rtmp, ...) that uses some 2-4 threads per stream and handles up to 100 streams with no problem, thus some hundred threads pose absolutely no problem - it runs 24/7, consumes about 0% of the CPU.